# A Binary Classification of determining whether a given word is disease or not

Tags: nlp, classification, nltk, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I wrote a code for predicting disease in a given sentence.
The following are the features used

```
POS Tags
IOB tagger
```

Output was simple either the given word is disease or not a disease.
I have made a LSTM model with following specification.

```
256 hidden units (Single Layered)
20% droupout
20 epochs
1 batch size
```

Astonishingly I got a 100% accuracy on  private test cases (i.e. On documents which were not trained), is this even possible ?

Comment: What's in the IOB tags? If they record what's a disease term, you're just looking up the answer from the features.

Comment: A sentence are tagged on the basis of IOB tag as followed. "The patient was suffering from acute dehydration ".Then IOB for this would be "The[O] patient[O] was[O] suffering[O] from[O] acute[B] dehydration[I] ".

Comment: So I was right? If you are passing these IOB tags as input to the classifier, your "features" include the property you are looking for. All your classifier has to do is pay attention to the IOB tags you give it, and spit them back to you. To put it a different way: If you find a random paragraph off the internet, how will you compute the IOB tags that your classifier needs to see to do its job? It seems that you need a classifier in order to use your classifier.